# Efficent Method for limiting loop

Tags: python, list, loops, variables, time-complexity

I am not sure what should I put for the title so I ended up with some random words.
I got a doubt on which way is better to write the code. Here is the sample python code

### method - 1

```py
list = [foo.....]
for i in range(len(list)):
   foo....
```

### method - 2

```py
list = [foo....]
length = len(list)
for i in range(length):
    foo....
```

Which is the better way to write or represent the code. Will there be any change in run time or memory usage.

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name it is a reserved keyword. Just iterate like this `for item in my_sequence` and you will have direct access to list elements.

Comment: @jlandercy I have just used ```list``` to make sure my point is clear

Comment: What is your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Summary:**

Processing time is not relevant, just try to write beautiful code.

***If you don't need the index, use this:***

```
my_list = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

for item in my_list:
    print(item)
```

> It will return "a", "b", "c" and "d".

***If you need the index, use this:***

```
my_list = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

for index, item in enumerate(my_list):
    print(f'{index} - {item}')
```

> It will return "0 - a", "1 - b", "2 - c" and "3 - d".

***About the time***

Now, thinking only about the time for processment, then i put then to run 10,000,000 loops and just a 'pass', so we have this:

```
lista = [1] * 10000000
for i in range(len(lista)):
    pass
```

> Function took 0.2820 seconds.

```
lista = [1] * 10000000
length = len(lista)
for i in range(length):
    pass
```

> Function took 0.2910 seconds.

```
lista = [1] * 10000000
for item in lista:
    pass
```

> Function took 0.1700 seconds.

```
lista = [1] * 10000000
for index, item in enumerate(lista):
    pass
```

> Function took 0.4710 seconds.

Comment: But my question is not that my question is whether will there be change in time and space complexities

Comment: @pavansai Oh. So a homework question?

Comment: @JimG. No, I just got a doubt when I was doing some coading practise